# RoboSpice - Not getting Cache Data

Tags: android, robospice

I am using [RoboSpice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) to making web-service calls as ,below.

```
spiceManager.execute(request, lastRequestCacheKey,
                DurationInMillis.ONE_DAY, this);
```

Bu each time , it makes network request using `loadDataFromNetwork()` .

Seems Cache data is empty.Got this message `"Cache content not available or expired or disabled"`

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved. For somebody looking for the same , please have a read.

---

- From the [RoboSpice starter guides](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Starter-Guide) , it is supposed to create custom Request (SpringAndroidSpiceRequest ; Based on the Model object) for each Web-Service Request.
- But I have a **lot of Web-Service Requests & different Model classes**.So , if we create separate Request for each Model , code structure will become messy.
- So ,Created a **generic Request**.
- But , **I was unable get data from cache**.So just override `getResultType()` .

  ```
  @Override
  public Class<Object> getResultType() {
      return (Class<Object>) clazz;
  }
  ```

---

### Here is the complete code.

```
public class WebServiceRequest extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<Object> {

private String url;
private int TIMEOUT_TIME = 15000;
Class<?> clazz;
HTTPMethod httpMethod;
private MultiValueMap multiValueMap;

public WebServiceRequest(HTTPMethod httpMethod, String Token, String url, Class<?> clazz, @Nullable MultiValueMap multiValueMap) {
    super(Object.class);
    this.httpMethod = httpMethod;
    this.token = Token;
    this.url = url;
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.multiValueMap = multiValueMap;
}

@Override
public Object loadDataFromNetwork() {
    Object response = null;
    try {
        if (this.httpMethod == HTTPMethod.GET) {
            Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse(this.url).buildUpon();
            String urls = uriBuilder.build().toString();
            response = getRestTemplate().getForObject(urls, clazz);
        } else {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
            HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(this.multiValueMap, requestHeaders);
            // Test URL : http://posttestserver.com/post.php  
            response = restTemplate.postForObject(this.url, requestEntity, clazz);
        }
        manageTimeOuts(getRestTemplate());
        return response;
    } catch (Exception timeoutException) {
        return response;
    }

}

@Override
public Class<Object> getResultType() {
    return (Class<Object>) clazz;
}

private void manageTimeOuts(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    // set timeout for requests
    ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
    if (factory instanceof HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory advancedFactory = (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) factory;
        advancedFactory.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_TIME);
        advancedFactory.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_TIME);
    } else if (factory instanceof SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory advancedFactory = (SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) factory;
        advancedFactory.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_TIME);
        advancedFactory.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_TIME);
    }
}

public String createCacheKey() {
    return clazz.getName() + token;
}

}
```

Initiate Web-Service Request and get Response callbacks , as below.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RequestListener<Object> {

    private SpiceManager spiceManager = new SpiceManager(
            JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService.class);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        String url = "http://192.168.56.1:8080/JSONRestWebServiceExample/JavaCodeGeeks/AuthorService/authors";
        WebServiceRequest request = new WebServiceRequest(HTTPMethod.GET, null, url, new ArrayList<Model>().getClass(), null);    
        String lastRequestCacheKey = request.createCacheKey();
        spiceManager.execute(request, lastRequestCacheKey,
                DurationInMillis.ONE_DAY, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        spiceManager.start(this);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        spiceManager.shouldStop();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(Object object) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ArrayList<Model> metricsResponse = objectMapper.convertValue(object, new TypeReference<List<Model>>() {
        });

        if (object == null) {
            onRequestFailure(new SpiceException("Something went wrong"));
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
        Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), spiceException.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
}
```